# Absolute url from relative path in an ascx file?

Tags: image, url, linker, absolute, ascx

Imagine I have an image hosted at `http://www.mypage.com/content/images/myimage.png` and I want to display it on my webpage. In my ascx file is the following:

```
<img runat="server" id="ImgLarge"  class="myimage" src="../content/images/myimage.png" />
```

The only problem is that this image doesn't print. I believe the fix is to have the image use the absolute URL but I'd rather not use `http://www.mypage.com/content/images/myimage.png` and instead use something like `src=@Url.Absolute('~/images/solar-panel.png')`.

Does this work in ascx files? If not, is there an alternative? I've only ever done this in my cshtml files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the image a part of the project?  Typically you would have your user controls in one folder and image controls in another (same level).  If this is the case, you would have a url like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ImageButton2"  OnClick="sortApproved_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/down.png" />
```

Other wise, if you want to diagnose whats going on, look at the rendered web pages source.  What does the url look like?